# Ahle Sunnat view of salawat to prophet Mohammad (PBUH)?

Tags: sunni, salawat

Where I live, Shia religious men coming to schools (specially girls schools) and keep Asking question to make sunni students interested to shia view of Islam. Recently they keep asking new question I can not find answer to help students.
The question is: "Ahle Sunnat believe in Bed'at (bringing something new to islam) and Ahle Sunnat says that Bed'at is wrong, But Shia do not believe such thing. If you Ahle Sunnat do not Accept Bed'at why you are doing it? Salawat to prophet is just آللهم صل علی محمد و آل محمد . But you, Ahle Sunnat, Keep saying many other kind of salawat to prophet. What proof you have to say other kind of salawats are not bed'at? Show us reference and text!"
Please help. What is the answer to this question?